# Function ST_Transform postgis 2.0

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I've read many forum posts on the function ST_Transform but unfortunately was unable to resolve my doubts so I posted a new question.

I have a spatial table SRID = 101010 and want to transform it to SRID = 101020, both already on the table my spatial_ref_sys

Initially I did the following SQL and it worked.

```
SELECT
    ST_Transform (geom, 101020)
FROM
    lotacao
```

Later I tried to update my geom column

```
UPDATE lotacao
SET geom = ST_Transform (geom, 101020)
```

And the error occurs:

```
[Err] ERRO:  Geometry SRID (101020) does not match column SRID (101010)
```

Comment: The update way does not work any more but you must use the alter table - alter column system. Read http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html

Comment: Thank you it worked, I put as a reply to signaling as correct! Just one more question (I know it can paracer idiot) when you say upgrade srid this redesign is the same as the data?

Comment: UpdateGeometrySRID actually transforms the coordinate system of my data? 
For in the PostGIS documentation it appears the trim ST_Transform (Returns a new geometry with its coordinates transformed to the SRID referenced by the integer parameter.). 
My doubt is UpdateGeometrySRID and ST_Transform are the same thing?